# Java cleartype text garbled/corruption

Tags: java, cleartype

Using java 1.7.0_40 though I've had this issue for quite awhile.

In a number of completely different java programs, I've seen this be somewhere in it.

If it's there once, it's been there and will be there forever if the program doesn't change.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F21k4.png

That is an image of the java control panel with the issue even; when I mouse over the OK button. Left side with cleartype unchecked, right side with cleartype checked. It updates the control panel instantly when I change the textbox, no need to complete the wizard or restart the panel.

I feel this may have something to do with me changing Segoe UI to disabled for replacing the default windows interface font. I personally changed it to "Delicious"

This only affects Java. I have seen this absolutely nowhere else.

Comment: does this affect only java? are you sure you've selected the correct panel configuration in the cleartype wizard? (have you run through the whole wizard?)

Comment: @radai yes, only java